# get checkbox list selected value does not work in typescript 3.0

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am trying to get checkbox list checked value but doesn't work

```
$('#c_Roles :checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    });
```

throwing exception

> Build:Argument of type '(this: HTMLElement) => string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLElement, index: number, domElement: HTMLElement) => TypeOrArray

Comment: Did you try `[...document.querySelectorAll('#c_Roles :checked')].map(i=>i.value)`?

Comment: I have tried     $('#c_Roles :checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val() as string;
    }); it works for me